# OpenGL Texture not showing up

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, textures, uv-mapping

When I create my cube, and I try to apply a texture to it, the texture is not applied but opengl returns a black cube, the texture is showing as a black color.
I'm using QT, here is the code:

(I'm using QT)

**Create Texture Function:**

```
GLuint AOpenGlWidget::textureFromRsc(QString place){
// Read the bmp file
QImage img(place);
QImage tb;

QImage fixedImage( img.width(), img.height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
QPainter painter(&fixedImage);
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);
painter.fillRect(fixedImage.rect(), Qt::transparent);
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver);
painter.drawImage( 0, 0, img);
painter.end();

tb = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(fixedImage);

GLuint textureId;
glGenTextures(1,&textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureId);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_3D,0,4,tb.width(),tb.height(),0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,tb.bits());

if(!tb.bits()){
    QMessageBox::information(0,"Texture loading error.","There was an error while trying to load a texture.");
}

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

return textureId;
}
```

**PaintGl Function:**

```
void AOpenGlWidget::paintGL(){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clears the screen and paint the bg with the color specified on glClearColor



// Another stuff (MVP Matrix... bla bla bla)

glUseProgram(programId);

GLuint MatrixId = glGetUniformLocation(programId,"MVP");
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixId,1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(MVP));
glActiveTexture(cursor_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,cursor_texture);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(programId,"textura"),cursor_texture);
// Draw or triangles

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);   

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,trianglebuffer[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,trianglebuffer[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);


glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,12*3);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
}
```

**Buffer:**
*trianglebuffer[1] (UV Coord):*

```
const GLfloat simple_triangle_buffer_txcoord[] = {
     0.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,0.0f,
    0.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,1.0f,
     1.0f,0.0f,
     0.0f,0.0f
};
```

**Buffer:**
*trianglebuffer[0] (Cube):*

```
const GLfloat simple_triangle_buffer[] = {
    // Front
    -1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
    -1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,

    // Top
    -1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,

    // Left
    -1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
    -1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
    -1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,

    // Back
    -1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,

    // Bottom
    -1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,

    // Right
    1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,1.0f,1.0f

};
```

And the shaders (Frag & Vert):

```
// Fragment
#version 330 core
out vec3 color;
in vec2 thcoord;
in vec2 UV;
uniform sampler2D d_textura;
void main(){
color = texture(d_textura,thcoord).rgb;
}
// Vertex
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 tcoord;
out vec2 thcoord;
uniform mat4 MVP;
void main(){
vec4 v = vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);
thcoord=tcoord;
gl_Position = MVP * v;
}
```

It's a little bit difficult for me to understand the UV Coordinates...

Comment: Is your glTexImage2D call wrong? glTexImage2D(**GL_TEXTURE_3D**,0,4,tb.width(),tb.height(),0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,tb.bits()); ?

Comment: Woah!! Look at that! That's it, it's fixed now, JasonD, Thanks a lot!1 Really I spent like 5 hours looking up and only for a bad typing... (Sorry for my grammar, it sucks)
:) Thank u thank u thank u!
Can you publish that answer for mark it as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your glTexImage2D call wrong?

glTexImage2D(**GL_TEXTURE_3D**,0,4,tb.width(),tb.height(),0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,tb.bits()); ?

Comment: Thank you very much, is fixed now =D